# Xcode 6 integrate remotely

Tags: continuous-integration, xcode6, osx-server

We used *XCode 5 Continues Integration* in our company. There was a bot for our QA Team, I configured it to upload builds on *TestFlight* service. Testers, when they needed a build to test last changes in app, opened *XCode bots web page*, pressed *"Integrate"* button, integrate starts and on finish uploads a build to TF, testers got an email with the installation link.

Here is the link I found in web, it illustrates the old bots web page. There is a button to start integrate along the bot name:
http://matt.vlasach.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Xcode-All-Bots.png

After upgrade to *XCode* 6 and last version of *OS X Server*  the manage bots web page doesn't have *"Integrate"* button, integrate is performing from *XCode*. I really don't want  QA team installs XCode to start integration.

The new bots web page without integrate button:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_guide-continuous_integration/art/bots_website_summary_2x.png

On *WWDC 2014 "Continuous Integration with Xcode 6"* video Apple guy uses Jeewes -  a Jabber robot that can start Integrate without XCode. As I understand should be a script that this robot calls.

***The question is:*** *How they setup launch integrate remotely, so the people without XCode can run bots.*

Thank you.

Comment: Hi do you have any news about tis?

Answer (score 1):

Apple has removed this feature. Not sure why. You can file an issue with them and hope they will look into it.

Your best bet is letting them remotely access a machine and kick it off from xcode there.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to check out this answer

[Using script to fire Xcode bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29679984/using-script-to-fire-xcode-bot/30062418#30062418)

You can use the apple api to get JSON responses from os x server, so you can ask for all bots, get their IDs and names, show that remotely to a user who can tap on one, which then sends a POST to os x server to activate the bot.