# Using script to fire Xcode bot

Tags: xcode, osx-server, xcode-bots

Is there a way to manually fire existing Xcode bots using shell scripts? I have a manual bot and I'd like to fire it based on certain custom logic criteria.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes.

You'll need to do a couple of things:
Firstly, I'm going to call your Xcode Server's IP address XCS_IP, usually localhost if you're on the machine where Xcode Server's running.

- Find out the ID of the bot: in Terminal, run `curl -k "https://XCS_IP:20343/api/bots"`. Copy the output to some editor and find the value for key `_id` for your bot, will be something like `6b3de48352a8126ce7e08ecf85093613`. Let's call it `BOT_ID`.
- Trigger an integration by running `curl -k -X POST -u "username:password" "https://XCS_IP:20343/api/bots/BOT_ID/integrations" -i`

Where `username` and `password` are credentials of a user that is allowed to create bots on the server, an admin will do.

If you're interested in more details, I have an app in Swift that uses that API and many more: https://github.com/czechboy0/Buildasaur/blob/master/BuildaCIServer/XcodeServer.swift#L324

And checkout my article on how to find Xcode Server's API "documentation": http://honzadvorsky.com/blog/2015/5/4/under-the-hood-of-xcode-server.

TL;DR? On your Mac, look at `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/share/xcs/xcsd/routes/routes.js`, where you can find the available APIs.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Just to add - it's written using node.js.

Comment: Also as of  Xcode7 beta5, the routes.js has been split into separate files.

Comment: @Eimantas Yeah that changed slightly in Xcode 7, but the gist is the same. Actually, I wrote a CLI tool for doing some of these things quickly: https://github.com/czechboy0/xcskarel

Answer (score 1):

Apple has added documentation for the Xcode server API that you can use to trigger bots.

https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/XcodeServerAPIReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016472-CH1-SW1

Below is some example code on how you can make a python script that triggers a bot.

```
import requests

xcodeIP = '1.2.3.4.5'

def main():
    botName = "name of bot"
    runBot(botName)

def runBot(botName):
    requests.post(xcodeIP + '/api/bots/' + getBot(botName)["_id"] + '/integrations', auth=('username', 'password'), verify=False)

def getBot(botName):
    botIDRequest = requests.get(xcodeIP + '/api/bots', auth=('username', 'password'), verify=False)
    bots = botIDRequest.json()["results"]
    for bot in bots:
        if bot["name"] == botName:
            return bot

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```