# How to cancel/abort an XCode Bot Integration in Before Integration Script

Tags: continuous-integration, xcode7, xcode-bots, xcode-server

I have a bot working on commit and it increases the build number and pushes to the same branch. I check the commit's user in Before integration script, and if it is the CI user (which is only and only used to push the increase number commits) i want to abort current integration. I saw this one:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30062418/767329

```
/xcode/api/integrations/INTEGRATION_ID/cancel
```

This one makes a curl call to stop the integration but i want to stop the current integration before it starts. I know i may also check and push the increase commit if the bot is not run by ci user's increase commit lately. But i dont want even archive to work if it is a ci user commit (i want the integration to be aborted even before it starts).

Comment: WORKAROUND SOLUTION: In before integration script i remove/delete the whole project folder so it gives an error and integration fails.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no way to cancel an integration before it even starts. You could use a pre-integration trigger to stop the integration from going further given whatever conditions you are looking for.

If your only goal is to bump the build number, I would suggest you use the Xcode Server environment variable 'XCS_INTEGRATION_NUMBER' in your build number field.

[image: Xcode Target Version and Build Numbers]

Whenever Xcode Server integrates your project, it will automatically use the integration number as the build number. These will always be unique.

Comment: What i need to do is
1. creating an archive file whenever a new commit is pushed to a branch.
2. increasing the version number with a CI git user & push the change to master branch
3. (since there is a new commit to the branch Xcode Server tries to do 1-2 and it becomes a loop) To prevent the loop, i check the commit's user == CI_user, and i want to quit the integration.